# Nested JSON object not saving to database MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have three mongo schemas, each nest into one another. The main one has a nested JSON, which also has a nested JSON inside that. However, when the User is saved using the main Schema, the other two nested schemas aren't being saved with their default values, why? Here's an example of my three schemas (just an example data structure):

```
const userContacts = new mongoose.Schema({
user1PhoneNumber: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
},
user2PhoneNumber: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
}
})

const contact = new mongoose.Schema({
phoneNumber: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
},
contacts: {
    type: userContacts
}
})

const finalUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 255
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 255,
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 10,
    max: 1024,
},
contactDetails: {
    type: contact
}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', finalUserSchema);
```

When the user is first created using the mongoose model, the values aren't set as they will be used later on...but they should still appear in the database with their default values:

```
const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashedPassword,
});
```

What gets saved in the database:

[image]

Where is the `contactDetials` nested JSON object with it's default values, I shouldn't have to provide any data when I first save the user as it should just use the data model with its default values?

Answer (score 0):

May you should try this:
`contactDetails: contact`
instead of:
`contactDetails: {type: contact}`
same for Contacts